# Should I always use "was" in an action that's holding/presenting another action?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

Example sentence:

> **Aware I was heading her way**, the girl sprung up and circled the
>   roundabout bench.

Would it be grammatically or logically incorrect if I wrote:

> **Aware I headed her way,** the girl sprung up and circled the
>   roundabout bench.

(Sorry, I don't know the name of this kind of phrases.)

Comment: let me throw another one: "realizing I'm heading to her ...". I think all of them sound grammatically correct for me.

Comment: I'd never use the second example here. 'Aware that I went her way, the girl dashed over and asked me for a lift' is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Advanced English Grammar by Martin Hewings, while describing any live action, commentary etc. you must use present/past continuous to talk about background events and present/ past simple for the main events.

For e.g.:
*She goes (went) straight up to this man, looks (looked) in his eyes. She is (was) holding a bag full of shopping, just as she hit the man with bare knuckles.*

Similarly in your sentence, you should use the first one as far as grammar is concerned.

P.S. :Since I am not a native English speaker, I don't know exactly whether the second form would be deemed correct in colloquial usage.